# One to Many Count with one query?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, lumen

I haven't touched the backend in a while.. so forgive me if this is super simple. I'm working with Lumen v.5.6.1.

```
| table.sets     |    | table.indexed_items             |
|----------------|    |---------------------------------|
| ID | SET       |    | ID | setId | itemId | have      |    
|----|-----------|    |----|-------|--------|-----------|
| 1  | set name 1|    | 1  | 3     | 1      | 2         |
| 2  | set name 2|    | 2  | 3     | 2      | 1         |
| 3  | set name 3|    | 3  | 3     | 3      | 4         |
                      | 4  | 2     | 4      | 1         |
                      | 5  | 2     | 5      | 3         |
                      | 6  | 2     | 6      | 1         |
```

How would I return in one query, groupedBy/distinct by setId (with set name as a left join?) to have a return like this:

```
[
   setId: 2,
   name: 'set name 2',
   haveTotal: 5,
],
[
   setId: 3,
   name: 'set name 3',
   haveTotal: 7,
]
```

Comment: Are you looking for PHP code, MySQL code, or both?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen either, whatever is easier for you. If you want to just give me raw SQL I can convert it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a raw MySQL query which should work.  To convert this to Laravel should not be too much work, though you might need to use `DB::raw` once or twice.

```
SELECT
    s.ID AS setId,
    s.`SET` AS name,
    COALESCE(SUM(ii.have), 0) AS haveTotal
FROM sets s
LEFT JOIN indexed_items ii
    ON s.ID = ii.setId
GROUP BY
    s.ID;
```

### Demo

If you don't want to return sets having no entries in the `indexed_items` table, then you may remove the call to `COALESCE`, and you may also use an inner join instead of a left join.

Note that using `SET` to name your tables and columns is not a good idea because it is a MySQL keyword.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked, and yes, these are not the real names of anything. Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using or want to use eloquent, you can do something like:

`$sets = App\Sets::withCount('indexed_items')->get();`

This will return a collection with a column name `indexed_items_count`

Obviously you will need to change depending on your model names.

[Here are the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models)

Comment: I'll have to take a look at this as well, thank you for your answer too!

Answer (score 1):

I always use in my project for count relation ship record.

```
$sets->indexed_items->count();
```

Comment: I also use this.but use with in get multiple row at time in foreach that time it down your project speed